# What are the total number of possible ordered trees with N nodes?

Tags: algorithm, tree, structure, computer-science, catalan

For example for N=3, we can find easily by listing them all, but when asked for any arbitrary N value I am facing problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math. Consider posting it to math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Comment: What would be your answer for N=3? 5 or 12? Could you specify what kind of trees do you mean? Binary trees, or arbitrary.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: for example three nodes are a,b,c; abc, cba, bac, cab, acb, bca; where middle element is root and left and right elements are its left and right nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at binary trees then, as mcdowella said, Choose(2n,n)/(n+1) (Catalan number) is the answer.

If you are looking at arbitrary trees then it is probably n. n^(n-2) = n^(n-1), but I am not totally sure. [Prufer's algo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence) tells us that there are n^(n-2) labeled trees and any of the nodes can be made a root, thus we get the number n^(n-1).

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in Knuth Vol 1 (The Art of Computer Programming: Fundamental Algorithms) section 2.3.4.4 About half a page of maths gives you Choose(2n, n) / (n + 1) and searching for the sequence in Knuth finds http://oeis.org/A000108

Answer (score 0):

You could go about it like this using dynamic programming : 
 
Let's `fix element i as the root` of the tree. Now we need to know `how many different trees` we can form with `the first (i-1) elements and the rest (n-i-1) elements`.
So we follow the same procedure for these two subarrays `(i-1)` and `(n-i-1)` to obtain the following recurrence:

**Formula:**

[image]

**LaTeX:**

> Trees[n]&space;=&space;\sum_{i&space;=&space;2}^{i&space;=&space;n-1}&space;Trees[i-1]*Trees[n-i-1]

Answer (score 0):

Binary Trees (2n,n)/(n+1) (Catalan number) as the answer
  If labeled trees than n^(n-2) trees .